# iPhone camera app to document wear and tear of items?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, camera

I'd like to document the wear and tear of everyday items. For that, the photos taken must be taken from similar distances and angles. Is there an app that helps achieving the right angles and distance, for example by overlaying the live camera image (before shooting) with a semitransparent older image or by using markers on the object? Or is there another way to do this with the regular camera app?

Answer (score 1):

Look for photography apps that support onion skins. Time lapse photography and stop motion apps are a good example. Frameographer gets very good reviews, but is a bit pricey. Check the web for alternatives!